# Selenium driven browser shows different HTML code

Tags: python, selenium

I am not a very experienced coder so apologies if I say smth stupid.

I am using Python (in Spyder) to get Selenium to fill in a website form containing username and password. Here's the target - [link](https://lta-tennis.force.com/s/login/?ec=302&inst=4J&startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DCAAAAXP8gqnvME8wNEowMDAwMDA0Qzk1AAAA4hLMKfg8CqJn19BT_ZLWGndBJrSrhwHIa6W021VJq31megsQ8gQwC0RFsbV4HvVIH69m9yWm358CSn0V6x160BbJ4RdZbraOVmXn70B_PuhQVmwtN223ahTC8YGG9J-4Bre8aejM2oWo55TpKBl_I4oZZj6RHW5S_qh3PLwfWktxItfo8zpDHH9dVqeCd9KyvscFjFsvEihxfLe-uYkjC7jwb5WHMGhJcKK7KCv7cHENsaATcSQZWPRGeq8J5j_PcaUt_zoeARO54c-9GcfJNBJ_L-mbhRF9yTLjfYaORbu43622u-twiDNQQsGHpA73V-l8v3DW10TbrqDEug03Z4zH3J5059_AQ7zXbQbV3iZRtnN4_2UOZ2wS2pdBfr5wDyfMB17uq_6BZ8XmMr6Ec308Qhbta0Se_fUaVgXL4A8lsTxun136x9fTiszyHvKnPBz3P2WmKnovgp53vCEpGNc6EQ7T-mcq7RfZ9uR8oyGTZgX-L-9zWBYr2i4OGE4iJoCjv_8VRf9mOIGG4RpisXNBNWjDrstNUXW1hEIRfqOsN1A6nfu6gAx8p46_AGgRgs_hOrPyomfDiPh0LgIdgCrx4QrcdlKwRz018dIRK-JMi19O-NuRbo7UEoIQx4g1jYv_A8nU7MSKLaq6z0gV195HSI_i4it7gZIwS6p0XdIL).

When I lookup the "username" element by pressing F12 in a regular browser I get the following:

```
<input class="slds-input input" type="text" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Username" id="172:0" data-aura-rendered-by="176:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="2">
```

So I attempt to locate the element using the ID. However when I run the script, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="172:0"]"}
```

Same when I run it in Firefox instead:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: [id="172:0"]
```

When I check HTML in the Selenium driven browser, I can see that the page code is (ie element ID) different, as below

```
<input class="slds-input input" type="text" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Username" id="78:2;a" data-aura-rendered-by="82:2;a" data-interactive-lib-uid="2">
```

My best guess is that the difference in HTML code is the reason for error. I found people posting similar issues but those were slightly different and I was not able to solve my issue using the solutions proposed there. I would appreciate is someone could help with my case.

Comment: Is access to the link private? if possible add it to the question so that it is possible to reproduce, so it is easier to help you.

Comment: @Fake, thanks - added the link!

Comment: @Nam Refer to the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath instead of `id` since it changes dynamically

Xpath for UserName: `//label/following-sibling::input`

Xpath for Password: `//lightning-input//div//input`

Sample working code which works in java convert with using above xpath in python and also add `implicitlyWait` and `pageLoadTimeout` befor launching the website

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://lta-tennis.force.com/"); // WebElement
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label/following-sibling::input")).sendKeys("dummy");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//lightning-input//div//input")).sendKeys("dummy");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Edit 1: Based on OP comment
This is working xpath
[image]

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately. I ran the following command: 
username_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label/following-sibling::input")
username_field.sendKeys("dummy")

This gave an error: "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //label/following-sibling::input"

Comment: @Nam Refer to the updated answer it is working xpath also works forme.You should add implicit wait. Add your code which you have tried in the question so that it will help us to make you resolved

Comment: Oh may I ask you how you figured the XPath? Right-click -> Copy XPath gave completely different result.

Comment: Using tools and extension is not useful. Master it by own.learn [this](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

try these xpaths

```
//input[@placeholder="Username"]
//input[@placeholder="Password"]
```

here is the full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\driverpath\\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://lta-tennis.force.com/s/login/'
get = browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Username"]').send_keys('hello')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Password"]').send_keys('pass')
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works too! Not have the "Wait" was the main issue!

Comment: Hi, may I ask you what tool you used to figure out the xpath?

Comment: @Nam i am not using any tool to figure out Xpath, we need to understand the syntax and find out "unique and simple" xpath for the element to get better results

Comment: I guess I need to educate myself better. Thank you!